# Can't get ant design field decorator to work on itself

Tags: antd

Using ant design 4. New to the framework. Wondering why the below code doesn't work:

```js
return (
    <Form
      initialValues={{ foo: 1 }}
      form={form}
      onFinish={onFinish}
    >
      <Form.Item dependencies={['foo']}>
      {({getFieldValue,setFieldsValue}) => {
          return (
            <button
              type="button"
              onClick={() => {
                setFieldsValue({ foo: getFieldValue('foo') + 1 });
              }}
            >
              Click Me {getFieldValue('foo')}
            </button>
          );
      }}
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
)
```

Obviously I'm misunderstanding something about the way ant design forms work. My actual use case is very similar - I need to render a component that accepts an onClick and updates the form.

What am I misunderstanding here? Is there any way to make something like this work?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug that was fixed in 4.17, despite any mention of it in the changelog.

- Stackblitz of Bug in 4.16.13: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-joj8ay
- Stackblitz of it Fixed in 4.17: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-emyams